# Estimating when does a certain binomial sum exceed an upper bound

Tags: co.combinatorics, inequalities, generating-functions, binomial-coefficients, lower-bounds

Given a fixed integer $n > 0$ and $0 \le m \le n$ let us define the numbers

$$f_{n,m} = \sum_{i=\lfloor m/2 \rfloor}^m {n-2i \choose n - m -i}{i+1 \choose m - i +1}.$$

For example $f_{n,0} = 1,f_{n,1} =2$ and $f_{n,2} = n+1.$ What I am interested in is the following inequality

$$\sum_{m=0}^k (n-m+1)f_{n,m} \geq f_{n+2} \ge \frac{(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n+1}}{\sqrt{5}} \; \; \; (1),$$

where $f_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number.

More specifically, I would like a lower bound for the least number $k$ such that the inequality is satisfied.

For example if $k = 3$ then the sum on the left is just $(n+1)^2-5$ which is clearly smaller than $f_{n+2}$ (for large enough $n$'s.)

Now the only way that I know for attacking this is to estimate $f_{n,m}$ by using the well known  bound ${n \choose k} \geq (\frac{n}{k})^k$ and use the integral inequality for summations. Unfortunately Mathematica (and hence I) cannot compute the definite integral of the obtained function and hence I am wondering:

> Is there some other way to analyze this inequality? What would be a
>   good bound for $k$ such that $(1)$ holds? Can the theory of generating functions help us?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the largest term (or two largest) in the sum for fn,m? That should help with a good  bound on k.

Comment: Can you check your example for k=3?  I am not getting n+3 for the sum of f's.

Comment: err you're right I forgot to multiply with the respective coefficients of $f_{n,m}$ hopefully its ok now.

Comment: Also, it looks to me like k will be Omega(n/log n) for the inequality to hold.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger Could you explain how you got to this conclusion?

Comment: Why use same letter for two different things? Aspiring award for bad notation? =)

Comment: It isn't a conclusion so much as a conjecture.  However, I note that your sum in the inequality starts with small m.  Your fn,m is interesting, but it looks like O(n^{cm}) for some c less than 1. Say it actually gets as large as n^m for purposes of order estimation. So you are looking for k so that n^k  is greater than 2^{dn} for some constant d less than 1.  Taking logs, I get that k is at least dn/log n.  It is very rough, but I think it gets you in the right neighborhood.  And you wanted lower bounds: here's one.